# Tar create archive rename root dir

Tags: linux, tar

I'm trying to create tar archive and rename root dir in archive. E.g. I have these files:

```
$ tree ./repo
./repo
├── 1
├── 2
└── 3
0 directories, 3 files
```

I want to create an archive `repo-v1.0.0.tar.gz` with these file structure:

```
./repo-v1.0.0
├── 1
├── 2
└── 3
```

Now I'm using ugly workaround:

```bsh
mv "${repo}" ${repo}-${version}"
tar -cvzf "${repo}-${version}.tar.gz" "${repo}-${version}"
mv "${repo}-${version}" "${repo}"
```

Is it possible to rename root dir in the archive using `tar` command itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tar` has a `--transform` option.
You could call

```
tar --transform "s/repo/repo-v1.0.0/" -cvzf repo.tar.gz repo/
```

Answer (score 1):

Tar will not rename, as far as I know. But you can do a simpler workaround using a symlink:

```
ln -s "${repo}" ${repo}-${version}"
tar --dereference -cvzf "${repo}-${version}.tar.gz" "${repo}-${version}"
```

You can then decide to keep the symlink or remove it.